# FileZilla - Drag 'n Drop doensn't work

Tags: windows, filezilla

I got a strange problem: The Drag 'n Drop of my FileZilla doesn't work.
The only [information](http://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8607) I've found about this is to re-register the fzshellext_64.dll / fzshellext.dll - but this dll doesn't even exist on my PC.

Maybe somebody has an idea what could be wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling from a fresh copy?

Answer (score 0):

Export your server list to an XML file, uninstall Filezilla, and reinstall. See if that helps.